# ANTLR3 c target: when rule fail, action still execute, i can't understand

Tags: antlr, antlr3

when rule fail, action still execute, why?
There is my test:

```
grammar Test;
options{
    language = C;   
}
@parser::includes
{
    #include <iostream>
}
@lexer::includes
{
    #include <iostream>
}

rScript
    :   INT LR RR{std::cout << "Action Run...\n";};

INT :
    ('0'..'9')+;
LR  :   '{';
RR  :   '}';
```

main fun:

```
int main()
{
    char teststr1[] = "111dd}";
    pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM    input;
    input = antlr3StringStreamNew((pANTLR3_UINT8)teststr1, ANTLR3_ENC_8BIT, sizeof(teststr1) - 1, (pANTLR3_UINT8)"-memory-");

    pTestLexer Lex = TestLexerNew(input);
    pANTLR3_COMMON_TOKEN_STREAM tstream = antlr3CommonTokenStreamSourceNew(
        ANTLR3_SIZE_HINT, TOKENSOURCE(Lex));
    pTestParser psr = TestParserNew(tstream);
    psr->rScript(psr);

    int ParserErrorCount = psr->pParser->rec->state->errorCount;
    int LexerErrorCount = Lex->pLexer->rec->state->errorCount;
    std::cout << "Parser Error Count: " << ParserErrorCount << "\n";
    std::cout << "Lexer Error Count: " << LexerErrorCount << "\n";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-memory-(1) : lexer error 3 :
         at offset 4, near 'd' :
        dd}
-memory-(1) : lexer error 3 :
         at offset 5, near 'd' :
        d}
-memory-(1)  : error 10 : org.antlr.runtime.MissingTokenException, at offset 5
    near [Index: 0 (Start: 0-Stop: 0) ='<missing LR>', type<5> Line: 1 LinePos:5]
     : Missing LR
Action Run...
Parser Error Count: 1
Lexer Error Count: 2
```

My question has two:

1. I can't understand, why the rule match fail, but the action still run?
2. How to exit parser when first error catch(lexer or parser error), i have no idea for this, please help.
   thanks in advance.

Comment: [offtopic] why do you use ANTLR3 instead of ANTLR4 ?